# Image uploader on register view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, model-view-controller, uploader

I have a process where a user can register and add a picture of himself via an image file stored locally. The problem I am facing with a lot of image browsers openly available is either they require something as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
                        new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

I am not that knowledgeable in MVC,Can someone suggest the approach I should take in handling this issue?

Image should be uploaded on clicking Register. Almost all of the image uploaders I found had a dedicated button for uploading.

Comment: How would you expect the user to upload a file if there is not a button to allow then to select a file? You can include a `<input type="file" name="image" ..>` input in the view and then post back the model and the file to `public ActionResult Register(yourModel model, HttpPostedFileBase image)`

Comment: can you explain what the issue is?  so far your "issue" is that you found many examples of ways to upload an image..... and what again?

Comment: @Stephen The only button i don't need is the upload button, i would have a browse button, Apologies if i wasn't clear. I will give you example a try stephen thanks!

Comment: @Scott I can't use most of the stuff i found online because they require an html begin form, and i already have the register form on the view therefore i cannot include another one (as shown in my original post)

Comment: @garyrizzo, So long as your include the `enctype` attribute on the form tag, then any input with `type="file" will be posted along with the model (and the name of the input must match the parameter name)

Comment: If you are using the default register actions in a default asp mvc project then you need to find the action for the register in the Account controller and apply the save for the image to the database based on `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0]`

Comment: Salutations are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by using the below:

```
    <input type="file" name="image" ..>

    public ActionResult Register(yourModel model, HttpPostedFileBase image)
```

Appreciate your help guys!